# Trying to get a list of all active employees in a distribution group in exchange via powershell

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

There is an all employees distribution group already in place, I need to get a list only of all "Active Employees" from this group. How do I go about using Exchange Management Shell?

Comment: So you got a list of  all DL members and need to filter out disabled accounts (like terminated employees)?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Get-DistributionGroupMember` cmdlet. The documentation for the cmdlet can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/users-and-groups/get-distributiongroupmember?view=exchange-ps).

Comment: As Peter reply, you could use this command cmdlet to get employees in distribution group. Get the group you want throng "-Identity" parameter